# НЕ могу получить ссылку

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Стандартно пользуюсь:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

получаю:

```
items = soup.find_all('a', class_='kf-cCRX-a9966')
```

интересующие меня блоки в которых (распечатал) находится что то вроде:

```
<a class="kf-cCRX-a9966" href="https://www.kufar.by/item/120232163" target="_blank"><div class="kf-cCRe-2aeee"><img alt="Apple Mac Pro ''Twelve Core'' (Server 2010)" class="kf-cCug-20d1d lazyload" data-src="https://yams.kufar.by/api/v1/kufar-ads/images/85/8555460420.jpg?rule=line_thumbs"/><div...................
```

Вопрос. Как мне получить ссылку `"https://www.kufar.by/item/120232163"`?

```
item = soup.find('a', class_='kf-cCRX-a9966').get('href')
```

не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно эта страница генерируется через javascript и soap не может получить эти данные т.к. в теле страницы их нет, вам придется проверить откуда эти данные эти берутся и изучить исходный код страницы на наличие этих тегов (Браузер: правая кнопка -> исходный код)